# Constant not defined error

Tags: php

I am trying to define my own function in one of the php login libraries. 
There some constants are defined which works perfectly fine until I call the databaseConnection() function on my own.

```
 private function databaseConnection()
{
    // if connection already exists
    if ($this->db_connection != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        try {
            // Generate a database connection, using the PDO connector
            // @see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
            // Also important: We include the charset, as leaving it out seems to be a security issue:
            // @see http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Connecting_to_MySQL says:
            // "Adding the charset to the DSN is very important for security reasons,
            // most examples you'll see around leave it out. MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE CHARSET!"
            $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_DATABASE_ERROR . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    // default return
    return false;
}
```

this is the function I defined..

```
 private function updateLastLoginDate($user_name)
{
    if($this->databaseConnection())
    {
    $sth = $this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE users '
                    . 'SET last_login_date = UTC_TIMESTAMP()'
                    . 'WHERE user_email =:user_name OR user_name =:user_name');
            $sth->execute(array(':user_name' => $user_name));
    }
}
```

when I call this function the error says that all the constants in the databaseConntion functions are not defined.. but they work perfectly fine other than the call I make to my defined function...
I am not good with pdo though..

Comment: @Jah I said its defined in a config.php file which is inclued.. and works fine when I remove the call to my defined function..though there are numerous calls in other function such as to login etc..

Comment: and the strange thing is that the function executes..

Comment: but you cannot call it like that in another function correct me if i'm wrong. are they in the same class?

Comment: yes they are in the same class.. $this->updateLastLoginDate().. @Jah

Comment: please join me in the chat.. I am there

Comment: There is no way to undefine a constant, whether you want to or not (at least, not without runkit). So however you are calling your new function, you are doing it in a way that is skipping the inclusion of your config file.

Comment: @rjdown I am calling it as the rest of the library is calling the functions..

Comment: https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced this is the library I am using